# Does change in each independent state in functional component triggers a render for the component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When we have multiple independent states in a component then if I change any one of them, will it trigger a re-render of the entire component?

**Initialise**
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
const [val, setVal] = useState(true)

**Update**
setVal(false)

Will this render the whole component again?

Comment: What do you mean by "whole component"?

Comment: Let us assume component "ParentWrapper" has two states, "email" and "value". If I change/update either "email" or "value" will it re-render "ParentWrapper"?

@Andy

Comment: Yes. The whole component will re render. However react will calculate what changed in the UI for you and only paint the updates.

Comment: You could easily test this by putting a console log in the component body and updating the state.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the Component will be rendered again. Let me add: Although if you have two states changing (almost) simultanously the state update will be batched. In React 18 React batches state updates in React events handlers, promises, setTimeout and native event handlers resulting in only one rerender.